# .htaccess rules to redirect certain pages and the catch all others

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm redirecting a site from an old platform to another. It's got 300-400 pages and all the pages have different names.

It's `learn.example.com` (old platform) to `courses.example.com` (new platform)

So I've put in some 301s at the beginning of the `.htaccess` file of the most important pages, for example:

```
Redirect 301 /courses-overview/ http://courses.example.com/courses
```

But at the end I need a catch-all to redirect any other page not previously specified as a 301 like `learn.example.com/whatever` to `courses.example.com` to catch any of the other 300-400 pages that don't exist in the `.htaccess` file now.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can Redirectother pages via the following Redirect :

```
RedirectMatch ^/.*$ http://example.com/
```

Put this bellow your existing Redirects otherwise Apache will redirect your whole site.

Comment: Any reason you are avoiding redirecting the document root?

Comment: @w3dk i didnt notice it.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks. But that puts everything to the home page, even the redirects I specified.

Comment: Your Specific redirects should be above this.

Comment: Yes, they are, starkeen :(